# Can't run installation script in new window

Tags: python, bash

i will get straight to the point.
  I'm developing a GTK program with GUI for Linux, and when the user clicks a specific button, the installation script should be run.

If i run my  application via terminal, which I'm currently doing as i develop it, i have an open terminal and the bash script can run.

```
#this works
python main.py
```

What my problem is, is that the application will be released as a regular application, that runs via .desktop file, as usual, which means a terminal won't be open.

I have been searching all over and can't find a way to run my installation script, with opening a new terminal for the purpose of the installation.
In normal situation, from bash you can run this:

```
uxterm -e -hold 'path to script'
```

I can't get this work in python with that:

```
os.system("uxterm -e -hold 'installer_path')
```

Because installer_path is a string:

```
 string=name.lower().lstrip().replace(" ","")+"_installer.sh"
 installer_path=get_app_installer_path(category)+string
```

So my point is, how can i properly open a new terminal, and run my installation script from the new terminal?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, your problem is that installer_path is treated as a string instead of a variable?

Comment: yes, since in the method the the installer path is treated as string while it should be treaded as a bash command or a path for a bash script.

Comment: I'm quite lost at your explanation, so let's get this as clear as possible. Is the following statement true? 'installer_path is a Python variable that I want to use as a Bash variable in a subshell, but instead, Bash is treating the variable as a string called "installer_path"'. Is that the case here?

Comment: installer_path is a python variable, which is string that contains the path for the install script e.g /home/user/Documents/installers/installer1.
Bash is treating this variable as a bash command, which gets me the error "installer_path command not found'

Answer (score 0):

To substitute a Python variable into a bash script you just need to format it like this:

```
os.system("uxterm -hold -e {0}".format(installer_path))
```

This should work in your case.

Comment: Thanks, finally this works.  Thanks for your time, problem is solved.